# Is it true that $E(X_1\mid X_1+X_2=k+1)−E(X_1\mid X_1+X_2=k)≤1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was wondering if we can show that $E(X_1\mid X_1+X_2=k+1)−E(X_1\mid X_1+X_2=k)≤1$ in general? Here $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent but may not follow the same distribution.

Any hint is much appreciated!

Comment: A counterexample given in a comment to your previous question could have been studied with profit, don't you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure this will not be useful to you, but it is generally not true. Let $ X_1 $ take the values $ \{ 1, 10 \} $ with equal probability, and $ X_2 $ take values $ \{1,9\} $ with equal probability. Then what are $ E[X_1 \; | \; X_1 + X_2 = 11] $ and $ E[X_2 \; | \; X_1 + X_2 = 10] $?